# Как создать метод класса, который будет самостоятельно вызываться при завершении программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

В созданном классе, необходимо создать аналог блока finally, который будет выполнять некоторые команды (`spi.close()` и `GPIO.cleanup()`) в конце работы программы, вне зависимости по какой причине программа завершилась (ошибка или нормальное завершение программы). Можно ли осуществить такой функционал в теле класса?

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью модуля [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)

Comment: Спасибо, вроде всё работает, как надо. Я сделал через декоратор `@atexit.register`. Как будет лучше, если вы ответите на вопрос или мне оформить ответ?

Comment: В ответе кстати дописал третий пункт про менеджер контекста, там как раз через finally отлавливается выход из блока или завершение с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Очень полезная информация для меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Можно зарегистрировать метод с помощью модуля [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html):

```
import atexit


class Someclass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        atexit.register(self.at_exit)
    
    def at_exit(self):
        spi.close()
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

2. Можно создать менеджер контекста, который при входе в блок `with` будет делать какую-то подготовку, при выходе - всякую очистку (вынести подготовку/завершение из класса):

```
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def prepare_interfaces():
    ...  # Тут вставить подготовку GPIO и SPI, если она требуется
    try:
        yield  # Передаем управление внутрь блока with
    finally:
        # При ошибке или корректном выходе из блока with "деинициализируем" интерфейсы
        spi.close()
        GPIO.cleanup()


with prepare_interfaces():
    do_something()
```

См. [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Также как вариант можно сам класс сделать менеджером контекста, для этого нужно реализовать методы `__enter__` (то что должно выполниться до входа в блок `with`) и `__exit__` (то что выполнится при выходе из блока).

Comment: А, ну, видимо, при наличии с какой-то версии питона встроенного механизма менеджеров контекста надобность в отдельных средствах для реализации аналога finally пропала. А то я думаю как же так в питоне это дело не предусмотрели на уровне языка )

Comment: Ну, atexit можно считать таким аналогом. А как еще реализовать синтаксически? Сделать "отдельновисячий" блок `finally` (ну или с другим названием)?